# overlapping with al three views

Tags: android, view, overlapping

```
layoutParams = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(0, 0);
    layoutParams.startToStart = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.PARENT_ID;
    layoutParams.endToEnd = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.PARENT_ID;
    layoutParams.topToTop = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.PARENT_ID;
    layoutParams.bottomToBottom = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.PARENT_ID;

    DrawView skinView = new DrawView(this, skin);
    skinView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    mainLayout.addView(skinView);
    viewArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    viewArrayList.add(skinView);

    DrawView dressView = new DrawView(this, dress);
    dressView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    mainLayout.addView(dressView);
    viewArrayList.add(dressView);

    DrawView faceView = new DrawView(this, Utility.orignalimage); // Create the first DrawView instance
    faceView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    mainLayout.addView(faceView);
    viewArrayList.add(faceView);
```

this is my code where i am adding them by creating custom class drawview on constraintlayout anybody help ,e to resolve this please

i am trying to add three view on single constraint layout and also adding them into arraylist and after click on item i am getting data from arraylist and using bringtofront function to visible the clicked position view on top of every view

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.